# Nix flake only works within devShell: how to bind python package to writeScriptShellBin

Tags: nix, nix-flake

So my school has a coding style, and thus a program checking it's compliance.

Recently they added `libclang` as a dependency of the python environment to their tool.
Only problem is, this env is managed by `banana-vera` using `boost`, which i succesfully ported to nix so time ago.

So i have a flake:

```hs
{
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixos-unstable";
    ruleset.url = "git+ssh://git@github.com/Epitech/banana-coding-style-checker.git";
    ruleset.flake = false;
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
  };
  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, ruleset, flake-utils, ... }@inputs:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem
      (system:
        let pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system}; in
        rec {
          packages = flake-utils.lib.flattenTree rec {
            report = (pkgs.writeShellScriptBin "cs" ''
              custom script, running `${pkgs.banana-vera}/bin/vera++ --profile epitech --root ${ruleset}/vera`
            '');
            default = report;
          };

          apps.report.type = "app";
          apps.report.program = "${packages.report}/bin/cs";
          apps.default = apps.report;
        });
}
```

So i thought at first i could just override the python env
`banana = pkgs.banana-vera.overrideAttrs { buildInputs = pkgs.banana-vera.buildInputs ++ [ pkgs.libclang ]; }`
which didn't worked.

I realized that `libclang` is not the same as the one provided by `nixpkgs`, and thus made a build for it:

```hs
libclangpy = p: p.buildPythonPackage rec {
  pname = "libclang";
  version = "16.0.6";
  format = "wheel";

    src = p.fetchPypi {
      inherit pname version format;
      platform = "manylinux2010_x86_64";
      hash = "sha256-nc3HMJOXiLi2n/1tXXX+U2bj7gB/Hjapl5nsCwwAFJI=";
    };
  };

  pyenv = pkgs.python310.withPackages (p: [ (libclangpy p) ]);
  banana = pkgs.banana-vera.override { python310 = pyenv; };
```

Which didn't worked either...

At this point, i tried to setup a devShell just to see if the package `clang.cindex` was installed.

```hs
devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
  packages = [ pyenv ];
};
```

Turns out, this worked, and `clang.cindex`, can be imported from the python env given by the devshell.
However, trying to build or run the `cs` script, and it dosn't work.

So, i tried to build it within the shell, and then it finds the package..?
Maybe it could be a `propagatedInput` then,

```hs
banana = pkgs.banana-vera.overrideAttrs {
  propagatedBuildInputs = [ libclangpy ];
};
```

nope.

Finally i tried this, along some variations of it

```hs
banana = pkgs.symlinkJoin {
  name = "banana-patched";
  paths = [ pkgs.banana-vera ];
  nativeBuildInputs = [ pkgs.makeWrapper ];
  postPatch = ''
    wrapProgram $out/bin/vera++ --prefix PYTHONPATH : ${pyenv} 
  '';
};
```

But it doesn't work either
I have tried all the thing i can think of, and yet no result.
If anyone have an idea to fix this program